# WSO2 Developer Studio on Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to get started with WSO2 Developer Studio on Mac OS X.
After following the steps here, 
https://docs.wso2.org/display/DVS350/Installation#Installation-Custominstallation

and re-starting my eclipse install (Kepler Service Release 1), I'm unable to find or locate the Developer Studio features.

Has anyone run into this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Per WSO2 docs, Eclipse (Kepler Service Release 1) isn't supported. 

I installed the Eclipse Juno JavaEE version and can launch WSO2 Dev Studio from here 
http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/
just fine.

After extracting the files on Mac OS X 10.9, I did have to run -
    chmod +x Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
to get Eclipse to launch.

Comment: Eclipse Keplar SR2 miration for WSO2 Dev Studio is now in progress and you may download the initial milestone for this migration from [1].

[1]. http://builder1.us1.wso2.org/~developerstudio/developer-studio/3.6.0/RC1/

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Developer Studio released with Kepler migration[[1]](http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/)

[1] http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/